# Best practice to hide username/password from outside world for UI Automation

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, password-encryption

Resources: Selenium UI automation, Java, Bitbucket, GCP, Linux VM

I have automation project which is maintained in Bitbucket, 
and I have VM Linux machine which is under Google Cloud. 
My team wants me to hide the credentials which is currently 
embedded in test script. And it seems like my user/pass are very where 
on my local machine, Bitbucket, test scripts, Linux VM etc. 
How can we hide the credentials here or at least limit the exposure ?

what I have done so far:

1. I removed credentials from test scripts and going to flush out
   BitBucket repo so that old commits which are having credentials 
   we will be removed
2. Work around - I will create text/property file to maintain credentials
   for little time and copied to Linux directory so I do not have user/pass 
   in my test scripts as well as BitBucket
3. I have found java utility classes of Base64 encrypt/decrypt, but No use of this.
4. I am still exploring Goolge Storage encrption/ KMS etc.

Please throw your ideas. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You said you have checked the Base 64 encryption option but did not find it useful. I would still say you can use Base 64 with below option:

1. Create an excel test data sheet or any property file.
2. While creating the Test script or filling the test data sheet you can manually encrypt Password (must have) and Username (if required) using Base 64.
3. This way in your test data sheet as well you will have the encrypted and protected credentials.
4. Next you can use the base 64 decoder utility and read the property file and get the required username and password and decrypt them using the utility and pass them to required web element. 
   This could be a solution you may want to work. Let me know if it suits you.

Comment: I appreciate your response but assume your code/excel file are hacked so it would be easy for hacker to understand that he/she needs to Decrypt the mentioned Password using base64, he/she will get to know right away. any thought on this ?

Comment: @MikeASP the code for automation will be either on the local compute or on the Bit bucket repo. If the central repo gets hacked then not only the Automation Code but the Application Code will also be hacked. Do you think bit bucket server will be that insecure.